# I have a cool suitcase. Might be tricky to ride a motorbike. Looking for a strap allowing to carrying it as a backpack?

Tags: luggage

Searching for `suitcase` or `straps` does not get me the product I want. I have a cool suitcase that I want to bring with me. It might be tricky to put it on a moped / motorbike. That's why I would like to carry it as a backpack, on my back.

Surely such product exists, my Google-foo skills are not good enough as there are other products competing in the space.

## Old pictures

[image]

Now it has another layer of stickers.

Great conversation starter / ice breaker.

#### "cool suitcase"

Not only riding a motorbike but general hiking across short distances.

Comment: Could you add a picture of some kind?

Comment: I hope you have you considered the safety implications. Such contraption may impede your movements, act as a sail when you are travelling and potentially break your neck if you manage to fall on your back at some speed. Just saying. ;-)

Comment: what is a cool suitcase ? cool as in cool or is it a brand ?

Comment: Updated question with the images - a little bit out date but gives you an idea.

Comment: Agreeing with Diego here. Don’t do this. There are plenty of racks you can buy for motorbikes. After which you can strap the suitcase to the rack.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but I'll post it nevertheless: **Don't do that**

That suitcase is way too big to safely strap to your body while riding anything, let alone a motorcycle.

Even if empty, is bulk will keep you pinned and won't allow any movement; and it is big enough to catch a lot of wind and constantly pull you back at anything over a few Km/h.

And when (not if) you finally fall off the bike, it will either land on top of you (preventing you from running to safety), or just break your spine if you land on top of it hard enough.

Comment: Updated the question - `Not only riding a motorbike but general hiking across short distances.` - including mud... I don't even know how to ride a motorbike, I believe that with 20kg and low-speed ride it could be achievable. I want to have backup option please.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may boil down to personal preference, you may be looking for a 'Monkey Strap suitcase to backpack converter' or a 'backpack conversion strap'.

It is kind of a combination of straps that wrap around, let's say a carry-on, and enable you to carry it on your shoulders like a backpack. There are a variety of places where you can get something like this and depending on your location alternate names as well.

It looks like and fits on to a bag as shown below:

[image][image]

Feel free to google search the two terms and shop online or at any local store near you.

If you really want to drive a motorcycle then another good way may be to use a rear end [motorcycle rack/carrier](https://www.jpcycles.com/motorcycle-luggage-racks). You can mount and brace/tie your bag onto it and not worry about having it on your shoulders during the drive. They come in many varieties and can be found at any motorcycle spares shop.